# How to add and save fields in database shopify?

Tags: customization, shopify, registration

We are working on a store using **SHOPIFY**.

**Requirement :** We want to add few custom fields in registration form. Right now only First name, Last name, Email and Password. For example we want to add "Company name, Mobile and Website URL".

Just to let you know that somehow we have added fields for front-end using "register.liquid" file and fields started showing in front-end.
NOW, we want to capture these front-end fields details and want to show these for admin.

So can you please suggest how we can fetch and show newly added fields data to admin ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, have you *tried* anything so far? reading manuals? looking at existing code? writing code?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes we have tried some changes in register.liquid and after that fields started appearing in fronend. But not sure how I can show then in admin as well?

Comment: Would you display code you used in your registration form? It would be easier to help.